# Маппинг int и string

Tags: javascript

В общем-то не знаю даже как правильно сформулировать поисковой запрос в гугле.
Нужна такая структура (типа enum что-ли), которая сможет сопоставлять числовые значения по текстовому ключу.

Что-то вроде:

```
Status = [
    Active = 1,
    Open = 2,
    Closed = 3,
    Processing = 4,
    Ready for Processing = 5,
    Ex = 6
];
```

Чтобы в дальнейшем использовать таким образом:

```
if (data.Status === Status.Open) {
    //Do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, можно использовать обычные объекты?

```
var Status = {
    Active: 1,
    Open: 2,
    Closed: 3,
    Processing: 4,
    Ready: 5,
    Ex: 6
};
```

Comment: Тока setter-ом залочить на запись.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, лучше [заморозить](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Answer (score 1):

В JS существует по сути несколько типов данных, примитивные: number, boolean, string, symbol. А все остальное является структурой данных типа хеш, который представляет из себя множество пар <ключ, значение>. Стандартный объект Object, подходит в вашей ситуации, его ключами являются только строки, а значениями, все, что угодно.

Ключи Object'а можно задавать как текстовые константы, а можно, убрать кавычки. Следующие два примера идентичны:

```
var obj = {
    'element': 5
}

var obj = {
    element: 5
}
```

Тогда в вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
var Status = {
    ACTIVE: 1,
    OPEN: 2,
    CLOSED: 3,
    PROCESSING: 4,
    READY_FOR_PROCESSING: 5,
    EX: 6
};
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript динамический язык, в котором все является объектом, что в свою очередь наводит на ответ - использовать нужно простые объекты (похожи на hash) -

```
const EnumA = { Active: 1, Close: "close" };
const EnumB = { [ NameList.Name ]: 2 };
```

Ну а в случаи когда значения нужно ещё защитить от случайного изменения -

```
const Enum = {
   get Active(){ return 1; },
   get Close(){ return 2; },
}
```

стоит обратить внимание что у объекта в качестве ключа может быть только строка. Если нужно в качестве ключа использовать объект, то для этого существует `Map` -

```
const ObjectKey = {};
const map = new Map([ [ ObjectKey, 1 ] ]);
// или
const map = new Map();
map.set( ObjectKey, 1);
map.get( ObjectKey );
```

И конечно же не стоит забывать о статических свойствах класса -

```
class Enum {
   static Active = 1;
   static get Close(){ return 2; }
}
```